# Chain map with one-sided inverse between isomorphic chain complexes quasi

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

Suppose that $C_\bullet$ and $D_\bullet$ are finitely generated isomorphic chain complexes. Let $f:C_\bullet\rightarrow D_\bullet$ a chain map with a one-sided inverse. Is it true that f is a quasi-isomorphism?

Comment: No, it is not even true for vector spaces, think about infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you! And if we assume that C and D are finitely generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $f$ is even an isomorphism of complexes.

I take it that the complexes are complexes of abelian groups. 
Since $C$ and $D$ are isomorphic, we may assume that $f$ is a morphism of complexes from $C$ into itself. There are two cases: $f$ has a right inverse, or $f$ has a left inverse.

In the former case, each $f_i\colon C_i\rightarrow C_i$ is a surjective endomorphism of a finitely generated abelian group. Such an endomorphism is necessarily an isomorphism. It follows that $f$ is an isomorphism of complexes.

Suppose, therefore, that $f$ has a left inverse $g$. The preceding observation applies to $g$, and $g$ is an isomorphism. Since $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}$, one deduces that $f$ is an isomorphism as well.

The same conclusion holds if each $f_i$ has a one-sided inverse, instead of $f$ having a one-sided inverse i.e., if $g$ is not necessarily a morphism of complexes. Proof by similar arguments.